# Trying to visually show the growth stages of a seed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an empty parent prefab, with 2 children under it. The parent prefab represents the seed, with no visual components. I currently have the first child active in the prefab, and the second child is inactive.

I simply would like the first child to be shown when the item is placed in my world (this is working currently), and then after a set amount of time I'd like the first child to go inactive, and the second child to display. I have all of the logic hooked up for knowing *when* to swap out the active prefab, I just don't know *how* to do it.

To throw a wrench into it, I plan on having more than one type of seed (orange, cactus, etc), and not all seeds will have the same amount of stages to their growth process. I'm trying to figure out a solution that will account for not just two stages, but 1, 2, or 3, etc.

Here is the logic I've written up so far - it is ready for the appearance swapping.

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Time.time > mNextGrowthStage && !CanLoot)
        {
            mCurrentGrowthStage += 1;
            mNextGrowthStage = Time.time + GrowthStageDuration;

            // TODO: Insert visual appearance swap here.

            Debug.LogFormat("{0} has grown from stage {1} to stage {2}. There are {3} stages remaining. Next growth stage occurring in {4} seconds.",
                this.Name, mCurrentGrowthStage - 1, mCurrentGrowthStage, NumberOfGrowthStages - mCurrentGrowthStage, GrowthStageDuration);

            if (mCurrentGrowthStage >= NumberOfGrowthStages)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("{0} has fully grown!", this.Name);
                CanLoot = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can easily do is to assign sprite for every stage of growth in inspector of your seed prefab, i.e.:

```
public Sprite[] GrowthSprites;
```

where each sprite from start to end will be representative for each growth stage (GrowthSprites[0] <=> seed stage, etc.).

Then you can simply swap sprite on runtime:

### Get SpriteRenderer on which you will swap sprites:

```
//Find or assign Sprite element of prefab in Start():

//Finding approach:
private SpriteRenderer _renderer;

void Start()
{
    _renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

//Note that you can have SpriteRender in one of gameobject's children
// and you can have several children with SpriteRenderer so:

//Assign from inspector approach - just drag appropriate SpriteRenderer
public SpriteRenderer GrowthSpriteRenderer;
```

### Swap sprite to appropriate one:

```
    if (GrowthSpriteRenderer != null)
        GrowthSpriteRenderer.sprite = GrowthSprites[mCurrentGrowthStage];
```